# How to reduce the execution time of the xcorr function?

Tags: matlab, correlation, cross-correlation

I want to find the windowed correlation values of `x` and `y`, which are arrays of size of 1*20000. Also, I want to extract the maximum correlation value from each window.

The `xcorr` function is taking too much time to execute. Is there any way to reduce the execution time? My code is given below:

```
k=1;
for i = 1 : stepsize : (length(x)-w+1)
    corrValue_w = xcorr(x(i:i+w-1),y(i:i+w-1));
    maxCorrValue_w(k) = max(corrValue_w);
    k=k+1;
end
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help validate alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the length of the signals.  Try using an FFT.  Here are some pointers: [Cross-correlation in matlab without using the inbuilt function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396814/cross-correlation-in-matlab-without-using-the-inbuilt-function) and https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12630/cross-correlation-with-fft-and-fftshift.  The first one seems most relevant!